# SWT Composite onload event

Tags: java, swt, composite

I would like a thread to start running as soon as the parent Composite loads itself.
What is the event and listener associated with such an action

Comment: Can you explain the use-case, i.e. why do you need to get notified and what do you want to do once that happens?

Comment: Yeah sure.I am starting a scheduler in the background.I am running the whole thing as an Eclipse UI application.So as a stand alone application the scheduler works perfectly but when it goes on to the Eclipse UI it gives a blank screen because of some thread issues.So I am starting the scheduler as a separate thread.I want the scheduler to start as soon as the whole parent loads.

Comment: Include your view in a perspective. Add perspective listener to the active workbench window and override the perspectiveActivated() method of PerspectiveAdapter class.

Comment: If this is about [tag:eclipse-rcp], please add the tag.

Comment: It isn't.Its about a Composite onload event

Comment: you add eclipse-plugin tag if you application is not an rcp one.

Comment: I think you are focusing on the wrong thing.I made it work.I am looking for an event associated with the Composite loading.

Comment: @Sher any how.. it will be helpful for others with similar problem, if you post your solution here..

Comment: I meant I made the Eclipse plugin work.I am looking for an onload event.Sigh.

Comment: SWT controls don't have onload events

Comment: This is what worked for me in  the end
parent.addListener(SWT.Show, new Listener(){
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
}
});